# Анимация картинки на Javascript

Tags: javascript

Хочу реализовать анимацию картинки, как вот на этом сайте https://bmfest.com, принцип работы должен быть таким, чтобы при ведении курсора мыши, картинка меняло свои данные в transform: rotateX и rotateY в соответствии с положение курсора мыши, помогите пожалуйста, как данный функционал написать на js, заранее благодарю за помощь

Comment: `transform3d` почитайте про него https://html5book.ru/3d-transform/

Comment: https://codepen.io/andrejsharapov/pen/yrOZvY

Answer (score 0):

За Вас, конечно, вряд ли кто-то будет писать с нуля, поэтому открою Вам небольшой секрет: если запустить интересующий Вас сайт в Хроме и кликнуть по странице правой клавишей мыши, то в появившемся меню будет пункт "Просмотр кода страницы" (Ctrl + U).

Дальше Вы просто вытаскиваете этот код (разметка, стили, скрипты) и смотрите, что и как там устроено:

```js
(function() {
  // Init
  var container = document.getElementById("container"),
      inner = document.getElementById("inner");

  // Mouse
  var mouse = {
    _x: 0,
    _y: 0,
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    updatePosition: function(event) {
      var e = event || window.event;
      this.x = e.clientX - this._x;
      this.y = (e.clientY - this._y) * -1;
    },
    setOrigin: function(e) {
      this._x = e.offsetLeft + Math.floor(e.offsetWidth / 2);
      this._y = e.offsetTop + Math.floor(e.offsetHeight / 2);
    },
    show: function() {
      return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
  };

  // Track the mouse position relative to the center of the container.
  mouse.setOrigin(container);

  //----------------------------------------------------

  var counter = 0;
  var refreshRate = 10;
  var isTimeToUpdate = function() {
    return counter++ % refreshRate === 0;
  };

  //----------------------------------------------------

  var onMouseEnterHandler = function(event) {
    update(event);
  };

  var onMouseLeaveHandler = function() {
    inner.style = "";
  };

  var onMouseMoveHandler = function(event) {
    if (isTimeToUpdate()) {
      update(event);
    }
  };

  //----------------------------------------------------

  var update = function(event) {
    mouse.updatePosition(event);
    updateTransformStyle(
      (mouse.y / inner.offsetHeight / 2).toFixed(2),
      (mouse.x / inner.offsetWidth / 2).toFixed(2)
    );
  };

  var updateTransformStyle = function(x, y) {
    var style = "rotateX(" + x + "deg) rotateY(" + y + "deg)";
    inner.style.transform = style;
    inner.style.webkitTransform = style;
    inner.style.mozTranform = style;
    inner.style.msTransform = style;
    inner.style.oTransform = style;
  };

  //--------------------------------------------------------

  container.onmousemove = onMouseMoveHandler;
  container.onmouseleave = onMouseLeaveHandler;
  container.onmouseenter = onMouseEnterHandler;
})();
```

```html
  <link href="https://bmfest.com/wp-content/themes/bmfest/css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link href="https://bmfest.com/wp-content/themes/bmfest/css/style-cache.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<main>
 <div id="container" class="video-bg fest-bg valign-wrapper">
 
   <div class="row">
  <div class="col s12 l8 offset-l2 center pad-top-40">
   <img id="inner" src="https://bmfest.com/wp-content/themes/bmfest/images/logo-2019.png" class="responsive-img fest-logo">

   <div class="pad-top-40 pad-bot-20">
    <h4 class="white-text">24 августа, Москва</h4>
    <h5 class="white-text">Измайловский парк</h5>
   </div>
   
   <showdiver-widget id="buy-button" class="waves-effect waves-light btn z-depth-0 fest-btn" data-id="dd0c4ba5-038f-4931-b160-769499da777c">
   Купить билет
   </showdiver-widget>
  </div>
   </div>
   
 <div class="sixteen-plus white-text">
  <h5>16+</h5>
  <p>Сотрудничество:<br>fest@booking-machine.com</p>
  <p>Фуд-корт:<br>food@booking-machine.com</p>
 </div>

 </div>
 
</main>
```

Comment: спасибо большое, очень помогли